# Visual Studio 2015 Extensions and Updates error

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 installed on my system. When I am trying to open "Extensions and Updates" window in VS 2015 using Tools->Extensions and Updates menu I am getting error "The input source is not correctly formatted." (See screenshot  below.).
I tried repairing Visual Studio installation but error still persists. Any pointers to fix this error other than reinstall much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: May be this will help - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/674d3b1b-056f-4d79-9e32-576f2f721506/visual-studio-2015-attempt-to-open-tools-extensions-results-in-dialog-the-input-source-is-not?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (info obtained from the link provided by Sanket):

1. Delete "C:\Users{userName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions" folder
2. From an elevated command prompt: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" /setup